# salesforce: browser dont open a Salesforce login page before SFDX: Authorize an Org

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I'm trying to Create a New Salesforce Project, but when I enter "SFDX: Authorize an Org," choose "Production," and then provide the org alias, my browser doesn't open a Salesforce login page. In the output, it just displays "Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org 20:03:24.63 sfdx org:login:web --alias myDevOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default," and nothing else happens.

I'm trying to Create a New Salesforce Project, but my browser doesn't open a Salesforce login page.